# Nextjs throws an error when using multiple root layouts with route groups

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, compiler-errors

Normally nextjs works fine in development but every once in a while it crashes completely, i have two route groups in the app folder and both of them use a separate root layout but nextjs tell me that /app/(web)/page.tsx doesn't have a root layout even though it does, it's like nextjs can't see the layout even though it worked just fine recently, also sometimes this cryptic webpack error message appears

```
error uncaughtException: Error: . is neither a posix nor a windows path, and there is no 'join' method defined in the file system
    at join (C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:1369036)
    at C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:293105
    at arrayEachIndex (C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\neo-async\async.js:1:7165)
    at Object.map (C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\neo-async\async.js:1:9971)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:293080)
    at runCallbacks (C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:1:168123)
    at C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:1:170035
    at C:\Users\Michal\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Side projects\coachbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:1:269268
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.385.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.385.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.1.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-alert-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-hover-card": "^1.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^1.2.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.5",
    "@react-email/components": "^0.0.7",
    "@react-email/render": "^0.0.7",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.4",
    "@types/node": "18.15.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^1.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.7",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.5.3",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "cmdk": "^0.2.0",
    "eslint": "8.38.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
    "formidable": "^3.5.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.4",
    "google-auth-library": "^8.8.0",
    "googleapis": "^118.0.0",
    "isomorphic-dompurify": "^1.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "lucide-react": "^0.171.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.4",
    "mongoose-slug-generator": "^1.0.4",
    "next": "^13.4.12",
    "next-auth": "^4.22.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-error-boundary": "^4.0.9",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-multi-select-component": "^4.3.4",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-search-autocomplete": "^8.5.2",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "^8.4.1",
    "sharp": "^0.32.4",
    "slugify": "^1.6.6",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.13.2",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.6",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "utf-8-validate": "^6.0.3",
    "vaul": "^0.1.1",
    "zod": "^3.21.4",
    "zustand": "^4.3.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/formidable": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/multiparty": "^0.0.33",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.9",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

can anyone help me with solving this?

I tried removing node modules and installing it again, clearing cache and removing .next, nothing worked

Comment: Okay I figured this has something to do with webpack but i still don't know how to fix it, here is the part of my next config responsible for webpack:                           webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
    return config;
  },